# Drupal openlayers form

Tags: drupal, openlayers

I'm using Drupal 6; I created a module for a custom content type and implemented all necessary hooks (hook_form, hook_load, etc.)

What I'd like to do is add a field representing a point on a map and letting user input it with an Openlayers map. I know how to do it with cck, but I'd really like to implement it directly in my code.

Any hint about using an Openlayers widget in a custom form?
Is it possible?

Thanks a lot for any idea.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, the OpenLayers and Geo modules allows you to do just that:
http://drupal.org/project/openlayers
http://drupal.org/project/geo

An OpenLayers cck widget is available which enables the user to enter a location via an openlayers map.